# Пагинация laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день, есть связь с таблицей через модель. Как сделать навигацию на на странице, чтобы выводило по 5 полей. Вот сам код
Контроллер:

```
$ObjConsumer = new Consumer();
$consumer = $ObjConsumer->get();
return view('consumer.index', ['consumer' => $consumer']);
```

View:

```
 @foreach($consumer as $consumer)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$consumer->consumerId}}</td>
                <td>{{$consumer->groupId}}</td>
                <td>{{$consumer->login}}</td>
                <td>{{$consumer->password}}</td>
                <td>{{$consumer->email}}</td>

        @endforeach
```

Comment: К коллекции перед get добавить вызов paginate(25).Читайте документацию https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

Comment: Пробовал, пишет что отсутствует еще один аргумент. Собственно не пойму, там еще какой-то массив просит

Comment: Моя ошибка, нужно вместо get(), all() писать. А как отобразить сами страницы? То есть выводит теперь по 5, но сами страницы не выводятся

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день! Попробуйте таким образом:

```
$consumer = App\Consumer::paginate(5); //если используется Eloquent
//$consumer = DB::table('consumer')->paginate(5); // или так
return view('consumer.index', ['consumer' => $consumer']);
```

Во view consumer.index там, где нужно вывести сам пагинатор, добавить

```
{{ $consumer->links() }}
```

Более подробно про возможности пагинатора в Laravel и его кастомизации можно посмотреть тут: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination